# How to bind to child view model property in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am developing WPF application with Prism MVVM framework. And I doesn't know how properly pass data between parent and child view models.

I have 2 view models - ParentViewModel and inner ChildViewModel.

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel
    {
        ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel(params);
    }

        private ChildViewModel _childViewModel;
        public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel
        {
            get { return _childViewModel; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _childViewModel, value);
            }
        }

        //This is does not work
        public int SelectedChildNumber
        {
            return _childViewModel.SelectedNumber;
        }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel
    {
        _numbers = new List<int>();
    }

    private List<int> _numbers;
    public List<int> Numbers
    {
        get { return _numbers; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _numbers, value);
        }
    }

    private int _selectedNumber;
    public int SelectedNumber
    {
        get { return _selectedNumber; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedNumber, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get and use selected value from child view model. My approach doesn't work - SelectedChildNumber doesn't want to refresh if SelectedNumber changes in ChildViewModel.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, What if I have ChildViewModel collection in ParentViewModel. One of this ChildViewModels have property IsSelected equals true. How to get this one selected view model from collection?

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel
    {
        Items = GetItems();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _items, value);
        }
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public ChildViewModel
    {
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
        }
    }
}
```

How to get selected view model? Maybe use a converter?

```
<someUserControl DataContext="{Binding ParentViewModel.Items, Converter={x:Static c:GetSelectedItemConverter.Instance}}" />
```

In converter I can find selected item. Or this is bad idea?

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, I beat this problem with Ed Plunkett help. Final version should be:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel
    {
        Items = GetItems();
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += ChildViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _items, value);
        }
    }

    private ChildViewModel _selectedChild;
    public ChildViewModel SelectedChild
    {
        get { return _selectedChild; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedChild, value);
        }
    }

    private void ChildViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var child = (ChildViewModel)sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildViewModel.IsSelected) && child.IsSelected)
        {
            SelectedChild = child;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you raising PropertyChanged event in SelectedNumber setter?

Comment: Because I am using Prism framework, I don't need to raise PropertyChanged event mannualy.

Comment: @taquion `SetProperty()` does that. He's good.

Comment: I was not aware of that. My apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind directly to the child property:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModel.Numbers}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding ChildViewModel.SelectedNumber}"
    />

<Label Content="{Binding ChildViewModel.SelectedNumber}" />
```

That's the name of the parent's `ChildViewModel` *property* in the binding path, not the type. The `Binding` now knows to listen to the `ChildViewModel` object for `PropertyChanged` notifications regarding `SelectedNumber` and `Numbers`.

The reason your version doesn't work is that the parent does not raise `PropertyChanged` when `SelectedChildNumber` changes. In fact, the parent doesn't know when it changes any more than the UI does. The parent *could* handle the child's `PropertyChanged` event, and sometimes that's done.

```
public ParentViewModel()
{
    ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel(params);

    //  Handle child's PropertyChanged event
    ChildViewModel.PropertyChanged += ChildViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}

private void ChildViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var child = (ChildViewModel)sender;

    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildViewModel.SelectedNumber))
    {
        //  Do stuff
    }
}
```

But you don't need to do that for cases like this one.

`ChildViewModel.Numbers` should probably be `ObservableCollection<int>`, not `List<int>`. That way, if you add more numbers to it or remove any, the UI will automatically be notified by the collection and the `ListBox` will automatically update itself accordingly.

Comment: Great! What if I have ChildViewModel collection in ParentViewModel. One of this ChildViewModels have property IsSelected equals true. How to get this one selected view model from collection?

Comment: In that case, the parent might want to handle the `PropertyChanged` event of each child. Funny, I was just adding that idea in an update when I saw your comment.

Comment: I have no idea how to raise events from each child. Can you show an example ?

Comment: @Oblomingo The child's call to `SetProperty()` raises the event. You're *handling* the event. See update.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, take a look on updated post. I don't have idea how to add handle to each item.

Comment: I showed you how to do that. When you create a child viewmodel, add a handler for its `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: Your `someUserControl` example makes no sense at all. Explain what you are trying to do with it. You should almost never set a `DataContext` explicitly. What do you mean "get selected viewmodel"? Did you read my answer?